# Spell checker has no dictionaries, LyX 2.1.0 (Windows 7)

Tags: lyx

Yesterday my spellchecker worked fine, but today I opened it to complete my work, and when I press F7 it tells me that …

```
the spell checker has no dictionaries
```

I use `hinspell` and `LyX 2.1.0` and I took a screenshot

[image]
[image]

I haven't uninstalled anything from my computer :(

Comment: Add a path to the Hunspell libraries and then go to Tools > Reconfigure . The path you show in your screenshot is for *you* to input the path. LyX does not autodetect the location of Hunspell libraries (hopefully we'll do this in the future).

Comment: thanks for your response but I did this : 
1)in the textfield Dictionnaires hunspell I gave it the path wich is : C:\Program Files (x86)\LyX 2.1\Resources\dicts
2)in the text field Préfix Path I gave it the path too wich is :
$LyXDir\Resources\dicts
3) and I make reconfigure 
but is still the same error :(
Note: the directory in my computer "C:\Program Files (x86)\LyX 2.1\Resources\dicts" it contains files : xx_XX.aff/.dic for each language I have (en,fr,de etc...), but I don't why it not work :'(.

Comment: you can see the screenshot I changed it @scottkosty and thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on then. I just checked and it works fine for me on Ubuntu.

Comment: ok thanks , did you show me with a screenshot how did you configure it ? @scottkosty

Comment: sure: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cve3azerxpws4jl/hunspell.png

Comment: my problem is still not solved :'(

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I don't know anything about Windows though. If you by chance have access to Ubuntu or other Linux distro, let me know and I'm sure we can easily configure it.

Comment: @scottkosty thanks freind ,so I will change into ubuntu and if will get error I tell you ;)

Comment: user54800 I can't tell if you're serious. It seems silly to change because of this. I'm sure there's a solution on Windows. I know spellcheck works on Windows for many people. I just don't know how to debug it. But if you do change for other reasons yes let me know.

Comment: ok, but my problem that this spell checker have been worked fine but one day it becaume not worked whereas I don't change any thing :(, so now for me I use word to use its spell checker because I haven't enough time after that i will check it another day and if I get solution I will put it here thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove „Francias” from `Utiliser une autre langue` (English version: `Alternative language`), and it should work.
(For me, it worked after removing, but not before.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Can you provide a little more detail and/or a screenshot.  I can't spot this menu point on the screenshots in the question

Comment: I guess you are meaning to remove `Français` from the field `Utiliser une autre langue` in the second screenshot. If it is right, please correct your answer.

Comment: You could add it may help to press F7 to verify current spelling is set top right to the desired choice ALSO the Text Style Language ALSO needs to be set for that alternative language to be spell checked for that language. As you have highlighted the Utiliser une autre langue could blindly be set to an incorrect value e.g. Francais without  any confirmation if that entry is wrong (in my case it needs to show **`French`** so removing any entry should thus default to the main language Français . Whenever a change to language is made then LyX needs to be restarted to utilise the change at restart